# Appcenter settings schema does not contain a key named 'reset-paid-apps'

Tags: appcenter

I recently updated my system and after rebooting I started getting an error when trying to launch appcenter about the schema not containing that key. I checked in dconf and it does in fact have that key. I have used this system for bitesize bug fixing for elementary, including appcenter but I checked to make sure there wasn't a schema file left over anywhere from that.

Any suggestions?